# Function defined differently on rationals and irrationals with derivative given by classic rules

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Today, one of my students was given the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3+1 \quad \text{ if }x\in \Bbb Q\\ x^3+x \quad \text{ if }x\in \Bbb R \backslash \Bbb Q \end{cases} $$

He had some questions on the derivative and he wrote $$ f'(x)=\begin{cases} 3x^2 \quad \text{ if }x\in \Bbb Q\\ 3x^2+1 \quad \text{ if }x\in \Bbb R \backslash \Bbb Q \end{cases}$$

Which is not true of course, but I was wondering if there exists some function where it could be the case i.e. a function defined differently on rationals and irrationals with derivative given by the classic rules of derivation like my student wanted to do.

The main problem I see is that the function will not be continuous at almost every point so not differentiable almost everywhere, right ? Or can someone maybe find such a function ?

Comment: If you define your function with two different expressions on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ it will only be continuous at those points where the two expressions match (given that the two functions are continuous at these points). In general you'll only have continuity at isolated points and so the function will be nowhere differentiable

Comment: Actually no, the function can still be differentiable at those isolated points. Take for example $f(x) = x^2$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$. It is only continuous at $x = 0$ and this is also the only point where $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Unclear what you mean/hope with "defined differently". You can define differently the $f(x)=0$ function for $x$ rational and $x$ irrational. For example $f(x)=1-\prod_{v\in A} |x|_v$ where $A$ is the set of absolute values on $\Bbb{Q}$.